# Composer - Checkout package with require_once in it

Tags: composer-php, google-ads-api

i have a problem including a private google adwords api-library version 4.6.0 via composer.
In this library there are files which containts require_once statements which themself than throw an error like:

```
PHP Fatal error: main(): Failed opening required 'Google/Api/Ads/Common/Util/Logger.php'
```

Composer.json looks like:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "google/adwords",
                "version": "4.6.0",
                "source": {
                    "url": "svn-url/3.3.5/google_lib/",
                    "type": "svn",
                    "reference": "Apility/"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

and:

```
"require": {
        "google/adwords": "4.6.0"
    }
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/google/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a general way to deal with require_once statements in the library for composer?

Regards
Kai

---

I cant remove the require-statements because its a library and when an update comes, all changes are gone..

I have tried it over:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "google/adwords",
                "version": "4.6.0",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://subversion.unister.lan/keyword-tool/trunk/API_2009/google_lib/",
                    "type": "svn",
                    "reference": "Apility/"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["src/"]
                },
                "include-path": ["src/"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "google/adwords": "4.6.0",
    }
```

But than the classes of the library aren't added to the autoload_classmap.php and the library cant be found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these statements usually depend on the include_path being set correctly, and you can do this with Composer as well. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#include-path

The better way would be to fix the underlying problem in the code, i.e. remove these statements.

Additionally, your own software should not declare the autoloading for that library, like you do now (i.e. declare autoloading inside the vendor directory). You are declaring the package info manually, and that package should also contain the autoloading info as well as the include path setting. See the smarty example in the documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2